# How do i ask a question in 'meta'?

Tags: discussion

Sorry, about busting in on "insulation", but being new to the forum, I have questions about how it works. 
But when I click on the "meta" button on the top line and then choose "ASK QUESTION", I am consistently directed to the OpenID page.

I read the FAQ, but found no answer.

1. How do I ask a question like "How do I edit my post?"    -Thanks, dj

I also tried chat, but all the faces were grey and I couldnt get it to perk up.

I also dont see a "Guidelines" or "Manual" nor are there tags appropriate to my question that I see on the one list I found.

I just cant seem even to use this site as I am told to without cheating into your group.  Please accept my apology and give me directions.

Thanks

davidjp

Comment: Not that I'm nitpicking, but Stack Exchange is not a forum, it is a Q&A site. That possibly explains why you don't get how it works because you expect it to be a forum and it is not a forum.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site.

The [privilege page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges) lists all the features that get unlocked on the site as you gain rep.  You need 5 rep to participate in meta and 20 rep to use chat.  The gravatars were grayed out because nobody has used the chat room in a few hours.

Your [profile page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/11710/davidjp) shows that you've registered and that you asked an insulation question.  To edit it, open the question and click on the 'edit' link below the question.  (Sometimes new users accidentally create two (or more) accounts and don't understand why they can't edit their own posts, but that doesn't apply in this case because you've registered your account.)

The [About page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/about) is a good introduction to the site and how it works (and how it's different from the more common forums that you find on the Internet).

Finally, don't worry about posting this question here on the main site instead of on meta (though you shouldn't make a habit of it): I've voted to move it there and I expect other users will follow suit as they see this question.